# angular2 rc.4: How to inject mocked services (provide() is deprecated)

Tags: unit-testing, angular

Since angular 2.0.0-rc.4 release ([change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc4-2016-06-30)),  both `beforeEachProviders` and `provide` are deprecated. My question is how can I inject my mocked service inside my component.
Here is my `beforeEach` function which creates a `ComponentFixture` with overrided providers:

```
 beforeEach(async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb)=> {
   builder = tcb;
 })));

 beforeEach(async(inject([], ()=> {
   return builder
    .overrideProviders(MenubarComponent,[provide(MenubarService, {useClass:MenubarServiceMock})])
  .createAsync(MenubarTestComponent)
  .then((_fixture:ComponentFixture<any>)=> {
    fixture = _fixture;
  })
})));
```

This approach works fine but as I said `provide` is **deprecated**.

**What is the right way to do this without using provide()?**

#### Edit

Based on Günter's answer I changed the line:

```
.overrideProviders(MenubarComponent,[provide(MenubarService, {useClass:MenubarServiceMock})])
```

to:

```
.overrideProviders(MenubarComponent,[{provide:MenubarService, useClass:MenubarServiceMock}])
```

and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the changelog

```
import {addProviders, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('my code', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([MyService]);
  });

  it('does stuff', inject([MyService], (service) => {
    // actual test
  });
});
```

Instead of `provide()` use

```
{provide: MenubarService, useClass:MenubarServiceMock}
```